# Marking a DataContract for inclusion in the xsd file even though it is not reference by OperationContract

Tags: enums, xsd, svcutil.exe

I have a class with an enum in it that I'd like to include in the xsd file generated by svcutil, however the enum nor the class is referenced by any OperationContract.  How to do I mark it for inclusion even though it is not referenced?